# Continuous Integration with hybrid mobile app

Tags: jenkins, ionic2

I have a problem. I need to build a job in my Jenkins server hosted by macmini (localhost) to automatic build a deploy for my mobile hybrid apps. That's apps was building with ionic2, and need a deploy for Android (apk) and for iOS (ipa).

But when i run a build from Jenkins, with this shell command

[image]

I get this error [image]

that's not all... because i try to execute, from the jenkins folder, the *npm i* and the result was this:

[image]

[image]
When i try to build my application from other "folder" and not from jenkins, they works correctly. How i can solve?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information hard to say; you can either just script the things you do when you deploy "manually", or you might want to try a CLI tool like https://www.bitrise.io/cli or https://fastlane.tools which can auto-scan your project and configure a suitable configuration which is then easier to tweak.

In case of Bitrise CLI the base config can be generated with `bitrise init` in the repo root, and you can also use a visual editor to modify your configuration: https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/how-to-experiment-with-bitrise-configs-locally-on-your-mac-linux/1751

Comment: i'm watching for fastlane, but miss few information on it because I never use before. Now see bitrise.io, and after put more information and screenshot about my job

Comment: in addition I tell you that I was trying to replicate what I do manually, in the jenkins shell

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of time, just find the solution. Jenkins have a own "tools management". So i need to install, into jenkins, a property version of nodeJS, Npm and all other tools i need to deploy the application.
So, first of all you need to install property plugin (in my case nodejs).
After this, going into Jenkins Management System and configure a NodeJS version. That's all